# How to display products in home page which are created from a program in magento?

Tags: magento

I created products using a controller in magento.The products are successfully created and are shown in list of products in Magento admin panel.But these are not shown in Magento home page.

But once I click on EDIT of these products and save them unchanged,they are shown on home page.

I am new to magento...

What might be the reason and how to overcome?

Thankyou,

Comment: Which code you have used to create product ?

Comment: are you reindexing after the products are created?  by default indexes update on save, which is why they show when you open and save.  You need to go and trigger them

Comment: How do I do that i.e., how to reindex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to flush all Cache you can do it form admin->system->Cache Management now click on "Flush Magento Cache" Button

secondly you need to Index you can do it form admin->system->Index Management

select all indexes and select reindex data and click on submit button now check your home page it should work.make sure your product should be in stock
and status = enable.

Comment: Is there any other solution

Comment: what is your site link ?

Comment: It is not live I am just a developer working in  my local machine

Comment: which type product you are showing on home page like :- new products or featured product or all types products?

Comment: Products which I have manually created are shown but created using code are not shown.I tried finding out the difference between the product which is created from the code and products created manually.They are both identical...Please give me a solution to this.                                                                                                           Thank you,

Comment: Please send me your code on my email id :- bablu_rai19@yahoo.com and also a snapshot of home page.

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-a-configurable-magento-product/ I copied from the code from this URL....

Comment: uncomment this line : //    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time

Comment: Hey all the products which I created using code are not shown in `Cataloginventory Stock Status` table.But I created products in admin panel and found those in the table.Also the products which created programmatically once opened and saved are shown in that table......

Comment: Can you help in saving products in to the `Cataloginventory Stock Status`  table also.....Thank you,

Comment: Hey thank you.I got it .while writing code I commented `->setWebsiteIds(array(1))`.When I uncommented I got it .